# Node Express hangs on request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

This is a tricky one; I can't exactly pinpoint where my problem is coming from, but I've reproduced in on both mac and windows.

I have an Angular 2 site bundled with webpack, which uses an express server via node for my dev environment. My site will load, but at one point there is an http get request for a json file `/docs/package.json` that hangs on 'pending'. It never goes through, and will eventually fail with no errors.

Interesting things of note:

- All of my co-workers have the project working at the same commit.
- Angular will fire a `console.log` immediately before making the call, but it never reaches the callback. Because of this, I have ruled out Angular as the root cause since, looking in the network panel, the request occurs but a response never arrives.

The relevant code snippet is:

```
init() {
    this.onReadyPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    console.log('This log will fire'); 
    this.http.get(`${this.constants['BASE_RESOURCES_PATH']}/${this.constants['JSON_FILE_NAME']}`)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                console.log('This log will NOT fire'); 
                response => {
                    this.parseDocsJson(response)
                        .then(()=> resolve(this.docs));
                },
                err => reject(err)
            );
    });
    return this.onReadyPromise;
}
```

- I have reinstalled my dependencies, including blowing away my node_modules directory.
- I have blown the entire repository away and re-pulled, and re-installed all deps. Same problem.
- I have removed both node and nvm, reinstalled, nuked the repo and reinstalled the repo into another folder. Same issue.
- I have tried modifying `/etc/hosts` to see if aliasing localhost would help. No use.
- I have tried this on node versions `5.8.0`, `5.10.0`, and `6.3.0`, all versions that multiple coworkers have tried and succeeded with. No use.
- I have run the commands from the terminal as well as the built-in terminal in Intellij. No use.
- I have changed no code. This project was working fine when I left work yesterday.
- I have tried it on multiple different ports in express.
- MacOS updated overnight. Not sure if that would have an effect.
- There is also a python server for this project as well, and the python server works fine, meaning that this is less likely to be a port-related issue.
- The issue persists across Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

I suspect this is an issue with node/express, since webpack seems to be bundling completely fine for the python version, and Angular works as well via the python server.

I expect I'll need to provide more info on my server config for anyone who might be able to help, but here is what I've got for now:

server.dev.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');

const config = require('./webpack.dev');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const PORT = 3000;

/**
 * Webpack Development Server configuration
 * Description: The webpack-dev-server is a little node.js Express server.
 * The server emits information about the compilation state to the client,
 * which reacts to those events.
 *
 * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
 */
const webpackDevServerOptions = {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true,
        errorDetails: true,
        cached: true,
        chunks: false
    },
    contentBase: helpers.root('src'),
    outputPath: helpers.root('dist'),
    proxy: {
        '/docs/**/*.html': {
            secure: false,
            bypass: function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
                if (req.headers.accept.indexOf('html') !== -1) {
                    return '/index.html';
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var app = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), webpackDevServerOptions);

app.use('/docs/', express.static(helpers.root('../docs/')));

app.listen(PORT, HOST, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.info(`Listening at http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

**Update**

The `webpackDevServerOptions` `proxy` is causing the issue. For some reason, every request triggers positive. If I put a `console.log` in the bypass function, it fires incorrectly on all requests starting with `/docs/`.

I'm still unsure why the globbing mechanism is parsing this incorrectly but I will post back once I figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, for some reason node globbing was matching all requests at `/docs/` regardless of whether or not they had an .html extension, package.json included.

The bandaid fix, since I can't figure out why globbing appears to be broken on my machine, was to return the request url if the `if` clause fails in the bypass function:

```
proxy: {
    '/docs/**/*.html': {
        secure: false,
        bypass: function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
            if (req.headers.accept.indexOf('html') !== -1) {
                return '/index.html';
            }
            return req.url;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I *do not* like this. I'd rather have globbing function correctly... I have no idea what I've just broken in other places on the site with this "fix". If anyone has any idea about the globbing issue I'm more than happy to mark a different answer as correct. But until then, this is it.